# Remove a class after refresh a page in react app

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a weird problem, I am building a website using react.js, and when I refresh a certain page, a className will be added to the root element tag, I need a way to detect that class and remove it once it appears because it makes the page messy, I have tried to remove it using jquery but that didn't work .

Comment: it is better to find what causes that class so it will help to solve the problems completely. do you have any link of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could import a css file and overwrite the styles of this specific class

```css
.annoying-class {
  /* change what you need, maybe even with !important */
  display: 'block';
  color: red !important;
}
```

In your JS just import it

```js
import './remove-annoying-styles.css'
```

I would recommend to check why this class is added, so that you can remove this unwanted behaviour.